# How do I add a line feed (new line) in a csv file (powershell)

Tags: powershell, csv

I have large csv file that should contain many records. However, for some reason, there are no line feeds or new record delimiters so as to be able to treat the various records separately (example by importing them to excel)*. Is there any way (eg with windows powershell) that I can add a line feed before a given field in the csv file? For example suppose we have an input csv file with contents :

```
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7,data8,data9,data10;data11;data12
```

The request is to get an output csv like this (so every record should contains 3 cells / fields....however this should be configurable):

```
data1,data2,data3
data4,data5,data6
data7,data8,data9,
data10,data11,data12
```

The above example is for illustration only. Consider that my real case contains a huge amount of data fields that I somehow need to organize.
Thank you very much in advance for every response

*Actually I have deliberately eliminated every new line feed from my source data. I did this to get rid of some unwanted newlines and other formatting characters (\t etc) that existed inside specific cells and totally messed up the structure of the data set. However, this way I lost the required newlines \n as well. Now I want to add them back, selecting the proper position they should be.

p.s. Since I am very new to powershell or scripting in general, sorry if I am making an obvious or trivial question.....

Comment: Do the messed-up csv files still have headers? Don't you have copies of the original files? Are the fields quoted or not? Why did you delete the whitespaces in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can "wrap around" an arbitrary number of values in X columns by calculating the relative column offset with: `$index % $columnWidth`

I'd suggest writing a small function for this, something like:

```
function ConvertTo-TabularCollection {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string[]]$Data,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string[]]$ColumnNames
  )

  begin {
    # Calculate table width and prepare list to collect input data
    $width = $columnNames.Length
    $values = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
  }

  process {
    # Copy any input to our `$values` list
    $values.AddRange($Data)
  }

  end {
    # Time to process all the input values we've collected
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $values.Count; $i++){
      # use the modulo operator to calculate the relative column offset
      $offset = $i % $width

      if($offset -eq 0){
        # We're about to process the first column of a new row, create an empty dictionary to hold the column values
        $properties = [ordered]@{}
      }

      # Pick the next available value and show it into the appropriate column
      $properties[$columnNames[$offset]] = $values[$i]

      if($offset -eq ($width - 1)){
        # We've reached the last column, output object and clear previous column values collected
        [pscustomobject]$properties
        $properties = $null
      }
    }

    # Test if there is a (partial) row trailing, output object
    if($properties){
      [pscustomobject]$properties
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can transform your data as needed:

```
PS ~> $data = 'data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7,data8,data9,data10,data11,data12' -split ','
PS ~> $data |ConvertTo-TabularCollection -ColumnNames col1,col2,col3

col1   col2   col3
----   ----   ----
data1  data2  data3
data4  data5  data6
data7  data8  data9
data10 data11 data12
```